Does Local Homeomorphism Preserve Semilocally Simply Connectedness?
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a local homeomorphism between two topological spaces. Assume $Y$ is semilocally simply connected (see below for definition). Is it true that $X$ is also semilocally simply connected?
Definition: Semilocally simply connected

A topological space $Y$ is semilocally simply connected if every point $y\in Y$ has a local basis $\{V_\alpha(y)\}$ such that the induced homomorphism of the inclusion map $i_{\alpha*}:\pi_1(V_\alpha,y)\to \pi_1(Y,y)$ is trivial, ie: $i_{\alpha*}:\pi_1(V_\alpha,y)=0.$

I think this is true, but I need someone to help to check my proof since I always mess up something that seems to be trivial. Thanks.
My attempt:
Let $x\in X$, $\{V_\alpha(y)\}$ be a local simply connected basis at $y=f(x)$. Since $f$ is a local homeomorphism, there exist neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$, and $V$ of $y$ such that $f:U \to V$ is homeomorphism. Therefore, $\{U_\alpha(x):=f^{-1}\left(V_\alpha(y)\cap V\right)\}$ is a local simply connected basis at $x$, since simply connectedness is preserved by homeomorphisms.

I'm not sure about the statement you gave. However, I'm pretty sure that if $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective local homeomorphism and $X$ is semilocally simply connected, then $Y$ is semilocally simply connected.

@Jon Thanks. And I think what you say is true: That's basically because if $i:U\to X$ is the inclusion map of a subset $U$ of $X$, then the induced homomorphism $i_*:\pi_1(U)\to \pi_1(X)$ is trivial. Therefore, the induced homomorphism of the composition map $f \circ i: U\to Y$ is trivial.

Well, I think you would need to say a little more than that! The statement does not have to be true if $f$ fails to be surjective or if $f$ fails to be a local homeomorphism, so both those properties of $f$ would have to show up in the proof.

I think I have a counter example. Lets get some intuition first. A space $X$ being semilocally simply connected means, that every point $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ for which every loop in $U$ is contractible when considered as a loop in $X$ (but might not be contractible in $U$ itself!). Hence it is a sort of mixture of local and global information. We consider if local loops are globally trivial. Local homeomorphism only preserve local information though, that's the point. You are right, that you get a 1:1 correspondence between small enough loops at $x$ and $f(x)$, but I don't see a neccessity for "pulled back" loops to actually also be globally(!) trivial. In fact your local homeomorphism does not preserve simply connectedness, only local simply connectedness so to say. Hence the last line in your proof is a bit sketchy.
Now to the counterexample.
Consider $H$, the Hawaiian earring (a standard example of a space that is not semilocally simply connected, a nesting of increasingly smaller circles glued at $(0, 0)$). Take $\epsilon>0$ small and consider
$$X = H\times \left(\frac 12-\epsilon, \frac12 + \epsilon\right)$$
a sort of fattening of $H$. Think of $X$ being nested (hollow) cylinders glued along the line $\{(0, 0)\} \times (0.5-\epsilon, 0.5 + \epsilon)$. Certainly $X$ is still not semi locally simply conneted. Now consider the space $Y$ defined by
$$(\mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}) \cup (H\times [0, 1]).$$
This is again an (even fatter) copy of $H$ glued onto the plane $\mathbb R^2$. This space $Y$ can easily be deformed to $\mathbb R^2$ (you can just completely flatten the $[0, 1]$ direction onto the plane, the homotopy is easy to write down), hence is simply connected. In particular every loop in $Y$ you might ever consider is globally contractible, so $Y$ is semi locally simply connected. Now consider the inclusion map
$$f\colon X \to Y.$$
Since $X$ is an open subset of $Y$ and $f$ is just the inclusion, $f$ is a local homeomorphism.
Hence we have a local homeomorphism from a non semi locally simply connected space to a semi locally simply connected spaces. So what you are trying to show must be false.
You can also directly see why this fails. Just because a loop in $X$ is contractible in $Y$, does not mean it also is contractible in $X$!

You can also take the cone of the Hawaiian earring.

Sure, that works as well. Just again have to make sure to include $X$ as an open subset again.

Thanks so much. I see where my proof does not work: I cannot conclude anything about ${U_\alpha}$, since we only know loops in $V_\alpha$ are contractible when being considered as loops in $Y$ (no information about how loops in $U_\alpha$ would look like when `embedded' in X). In order to conclude something, I have to assume $V_\alpha$ themselves have trivial fundamental group (ie: Y is locally simply-connected). Then I can conclude that the ${U_\alpha}$ that I defined also have trivial fundamental groups.

Yes, that also seems like a good way of putting it :)
